# How can I access to Google Play Developer Console Account with Microsoft outlook id?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am very new to android development, Please correct me if i am asking anything wrong.

I know we need to have a Google Account to accept the Developer account. But in our office we are using Microsoft Outlook emails as official emails

Today I've got an invitation to my office email id for Google Play Developer Console Account

When I was trying to accept that invitation, it redirects to Google accounts login page (obviously its correct)

But we should not use our personal emails for any actions in the office.

So can any one suggest me, How can I access to Google Play Developer Console Account with Microsoft outlook id?

Comment: The office could set-up a Google Account for all the developers to use. That way anyone can use it in the office and the Google Account is not linked to any one developer.

Comment: you can access google play store developer account with your existing email address ( it's not mandatory to use XXX@gmail.com ). When you are redirected to Google Accounts Login Page. Create a new account and at creation page select ( I prefer to use my current email address). Please note you must need to have a Google Account associated with a email address to access Google Play Developer console. In your case your email address configured with Microsoft Outlook email. Hope this clarifies your query

Answer (score -2):

Try signup google account with Microsoft ID and then access it

Comment: Post a solution,